# How to combine keys in hotkeys in autohotkeys?

Tags: autohotkey

I want to set up a hotkey by pressing `Alt`, `q` and the `Left` arrow. So far I've tried

```
# opt 1
!q & Left::
```

```
#opt 2
Alt & q & Left::
```

```
# opt 3
!qLeft:: M
```

but the only result I get once I run the script is `Error: invalid hotkey` in the line above. There seems something is wrong with the ampersand.

I can share the whole script if needed.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Custom Combinations](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm#combo) section of the documentation:

> Combinations of three or more keys are not supported.

However, I found [this class](https://www.autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=24145) that claims to

> enable easy usage of custom multi-key hotkeys.

I haven't tested it myself, but if that hotkey is important to you, then it might be worth trying!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a slightly janky solution using vanilla ahk and a timer.

```
Left:: 
If(keyPressed = 1){
   ...Do a thing...
}
return

!Q::
keyPressed := 1
SetTimer, altQTimer, 200
return

altQTimer:
keyPressed := 0
return
```